Font appears in font menu but isn’t actually installed. How can I delete it?
I want to use the Adobe CC Font 'Semplicita Pro' but I have a font 'installed' called 'Semplicità'. (similar name, but without Pro and with an accent on the last a). The Adobe font isn't working properly (some weights never appear) and I think it might be because of the already installed font. However, this font - the one called 'Semplicità' - ISN'T ACTUALLY INSTALLED. (Also, this version isn't quite right, it doesn't have all the weights I need).
It is not in Font Book, it is not in Font Base (the font manager I use) and there are no files on my Hard Drive which match it. When I take a copy of Semplicita that I have (OTF) and drag it into Font Book I actually get a warning that the font is already installed! But it doesn't show up in the list.
I have checked these locations as well as searching everywhere on my HD for it:

/System/Library/Fonts Does not have any font files who's name matches
the font name (Semplicità) - nor does the 'Supplemental' folder
within that folder.
/Library/Fonts contains one font - Arial
Unicode.ttf
~/Library/Fonts contains nothing.
My Font Manager(FontBase) stores fonts in ~/FontBase - But there is no file in there
that matches.

How can I find this rogue font which is somehow installed without being installed?

You're sure that Font Book is displaying All Fonts -- both in the sidebar and in the toolbar? And you've searched using the FontBase app? Does Semplicità show up in the font menu of, say, TextEdit, or Word? Also which font are you adding when you get the duplicate warning -- the Adobe Pro one, or the other one?

FontBook is definitely displaying all fonts.
Semplicità is definitely not in Font Base. (And Fonts installed with font base don't appear if the app isn't running and yet Semplicità is always in the font menu even when it is not running.)
Yes, Semplicità shows up in TextEdit.
The duplicate error happens when I try to install an OTF version of Semplicita that I have. We used it to upload the font to Canva one time.

When I install the duplicate OTF and choose keep both, it appears in FontBook and then when I remove it, it goes. The original is still there.

Perhaps clear the Font cache and restart? Also, test whether the font appears in another user account.

Can you do a grep -r "Semplicità" / to see where the string shows up in related system databases?

After clearing the cache and Reseting the fonts within Font Book I found the option to "Show fonts managed by non-apple utilities". When I check it the "Semplicità" font appears in Font Book. So that confirms that it is some app that is loading it. I wonder how I find which one?

Aha! After a while it disappeared from Font Book - I guess that clearing the cache did it. Many thanks.
